# Dell Latitude 5521 WiFi not working on U20 LTS

Tags: wireless, dell

I bought 6 new Dell Latitude 5521, configuration : https://ubuntu.com/certified/202103-28860/20.04%20LTS
when i install Ubuntu 20LTS system doesn't detect WiFi card, I can only connect via Ethernet.
When i install Ubuntu 21.10 it works normally.
What can i do? I want to stay with LTS and not wait till U22.04LTS

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please add the output of `uname -r`. Is you system up to date? Run: `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`. The wireless card should work with kernel 5.10+. Also, run `sudo apt install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-20.04`. Use [edit] to add additional info.

Comment: Please be precise with details; Ubuntu releases using the *year* format are different products to those using the *year.month* format, ie. 20 is a different system to 20.04. Which media did you use with 20.04?  Was it an ISO using the GA kernel stack (5.4)? 20.04.2? (5.8)? 20.04.3 stack (5.11)? or 20.04.4 stack (5.13)?  I'd try a different ISO with a later stack

Comment: Check what kernel runs in 21.10 and install that kernel in 20.04 LTS.