# Dell Latitude 5521 WiFI Not Working

Tags: networking, drivers, dell, iwlwifi

Note: This is not Ubuntu only. I've yet been able to get the wifi working on this machine. I've tried Debian, Arch, Ubuntu, Mint, POP, Arco, among others. WiFi does not work. I keep getting that the wifi adapter cannot be found.

Note: I've found this link stating this laptop is ubuntu certified.

https://ubuntu.com/certified/202103-28860

I'm currently using 23.04 Ubuntu.

=====

uname -r

```
6.2.0-25-generic
```

=====

rfkill

```
    ID TYPE      DEVICE              SOFT      HARD
 0 bluetooth hci0           unblocked unblocked
 1 wlan      dell-wifi      unblocked unblocked
 2 bluetooth dell-bluetooth unblocked unblocked
```

====

lspci

```
    00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 11th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 05)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation TigerLake-H GT1 [UHD Graphics] (rev 01)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation TigerLake-LP Dynamic Tuning Processor Participant (rev 05)
00:07.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-H Thunderbolt 4 PCI Express Root Port #0 (rev 05)
00:07.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-H Thunderbolt 4 PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev 05)
00:0a.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Tigerlake Telemetry Aggregator Driver (rev 01)
00:0d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-H Thunderbolt 4 USB Controller (rev 05)
00:0d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-H Thunderbolt 4 NHI #0 (rev 05)
00:12.0 Serial controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-H Integrated Sensor Hub (rev 11)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-H USB 3.2 Gen 2x1 xHCI Host Controller (rev 11)
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-H Shared SRAM (rev 11)
00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake PCH CNVi WiFi (rev 11)
00:15.0 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-H Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 11)
00:15.1 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-H Serial IO I2C Controller #1 (rev 11)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-H Management Engine Interface (rev 11)
00:16.3 Serial controller: Intel Corporation Device 43e3 (rev 11)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Device 43d3 (rev 11)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 43ba (rev 11)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-H PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev 11)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device 4389 (rev 11)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-H HD Audio Controller (rev 11)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-H SMBus Controller (rev 11)
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-H SPI Controller (rev 11)
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (14) I219-LM (rev 11)
71:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS525A PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
72:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: KIOXIA Corporation Device 000c
```

=====

lsusb

```
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 1bcf:2ba9 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. Integrated_Webcam_FHD
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 8087:0026 Intel Corp. AX201 Bluetooth
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

====
I installed windows and my wifi does work and drivers / firmware was up to date.

I found this: [Dell Latitude 5521 WiFi not working on U20 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1393589/dell-latitude-5521-wifi-not-working-on-u20-lts) which the sudo command mentioned there doesn't work i assume because the file is not named that anymore?

====

This is not a duel boot system.

=====
dmesg

```
[    2.415317] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: CSR_RESET = 0x11
[    2.415330] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Host monitor block 0x0 vector 0x0
[    2.415361] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 0]: 0x00000003
[    2.415396] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 1]: 0x00000003
[    2.415423] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 2]: 0x00000003
[    2.415450] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 3]: 0x00000003
[    2.415478] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 4]: 0x00000003
[    2.415509] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 5]: 0x00000003
[    2.415543] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 6]: 0x00000003
[    2.415570] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 7]: 0x00000003
[    2.415598] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 8]: 0x00000003
[    2.415625] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 9]: 0x00000003
[    2.415653] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 10]: 0x00000003
[    2.415680] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 11]: 0x00000003
[    2.415715] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 12]: 0x00000003
[    2.415750] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 13]: 0x00000003
[    2.415785] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 14]: 0x00000003
[    2.415793] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Host monitor block 0x0 vector 0x1
[    2.415824] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 0]: 0x00000003
[    2.415859] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 1]: 0x00000003
[    2.415886] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 2]: 0x00000003
[    2.415917] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 3]: 0x00000003
[    2.415952] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 4]: 0x00000003
[    2.415987] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 5]: 0x00000003
[    2.416021] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 6]: 0x00000003
[    2.416049] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 7]: 0x00000003
[    2.416077] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 8]: 0x00000003
[    2.416104] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 9]: 0x00000003
[    2.416132] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 10]: 0x00000003
[    2.416159] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 11]: 0x00000003
[    2.416186] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 12]: 0x00000003
[    2.416213] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 13]: 0x00000003
[    2.416248] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 14]: 0x00000003
[    2.416256] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Host monitor block 0x0 vector 0x6
[    2.416287] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 0]: 0x00000003
[    2.416322] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 1]: 0x00000003
[    2.416357] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 2]: 0x00000003
[    2.416384] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 3]: 0x00000003
[    2.416418] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 4]: 0x00000003
[    2.416445] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 5]: 0x00000003
[    2.416480] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 6]: 0x00000003
[    2.416513] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 7]: 0x00000003
[    2.416540] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 8]: 0x00000003
[    2.416568] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 9]: 0x00000003
[    2.416595] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 10]: 0x00000003
[    2.416622] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 11]: 0x00000003
[    2.416656] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 12]: 0x00000003
[    2.416692] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 13]: 0x00000003
[    2.416727] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 14]: 0x00000003
[    2.416735] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Host monitor block 0x22 vector 0x0
[    2.416766] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 0]: 0x00000003
[    2.416800] iwlwifi: probe of 0000:00:14.3 failed with error -110
[    2.417181] intel_rapl_common: Found RAPL domain package
[    2.417183] intel_rapl_common: Found RAPL domain core
[    2.417184] intel_rapl_common: Found RAPL domain uncore
[    2.417187] intel_rapl_common: Found RAPL domain psys
[    2.419636] input: Dell Privacy Driver as /devices/platform/PNP0C14:02/wmi_bus
```

EDIT 1: What Distro Version:

Ubuntu 23.04 desktop gnome architecture amd64

EDIT 2: I didn't use the ubiquity legacy installer. I used the big bright download button and used what the default iso was.

Comment: You mention many OSes without specific details thus the information is of no real use. What likely matters is the kernel stack being used, as that alters the kernel modules (*commonly called 'drivers'*), with Ubuntu LTS releases offering kernel stack choice. You mention OSes, where maybe you should look further than that & contrast what kernel (stacks) work & work from there. Your addition OS detail mentioned none of that. The certified link you gave had it working on an OEM kernel stack, so not GA or HWE defaults of Server & Desktop ISOs (you didn't mention Server/Desktop either)

Comment: Ubuntu 23.04 gnome amd64. I just went to the website clicked desktop and downloaded the iso and burned it to a usb using a flash drive. i'm not sure what info is being requested but i've been trying to get this fixed now for over a week :/

Comment: Gotcha, yeah I didn't use the legacy installer. thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos)